# getting value from URL variable and displaying it

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, domparser

I am trying to display a greeting message followed by the name value grabbed from the URL. It works, however if there is no variable name, nothing shows even the greeting message. What could be causing this issue?

```
<h1 class="welcomeGreeting" style="color: white !important; text-align: center; padding-bottom:1px !important; margin-bottom:1px !important;">
</h1><script>
    var url = window.location.href;
    var captured = /name=([^&]+)/.exec(url)[1]; // Value is in [1] ('384' in our case)
    var result = captured ? captured : 'myDefaultValue';
//var result = window.location.href.split('&name=')[1];


  window.alert(result);
  var thehours = new Date().getHours();
 var themessage;
 var morning = ('Good morning');
 var afternoon = ('Good afternoon');
 var evening = ('Good evening');

 if (thehours >= 0 && thehours < 12) {
      themessage = afternoon + ' ' + result;

 } else if (thehours >= 12 && thehours < 17) {
      themessage = afternoon + ' ' + result;

 } else if (thehours >= 17 && thehours < 24) {
      themessage = afternoon + ' ' + result;
 }

 $('.welcomeGreeting').append(themessage);

</script>
```

Comment: can you provide your URL from which you get values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It works, however if there is no variable name, nothing shows even
>   the greeting message. What could be causing this issue?

[exec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) will return `null` if there is no match found. So, you are trying to do `null[1]` when variable doesn't exist in `url`.

You need to first take the value in a variable and then extract value from it

```
var captured = /name=([^&]+)/.exec(url);
var result = captured ? captured[1] : 'myDefaultValue';
```